# Snippet encoded as utf-8 causes blank text to be inserted above it

Tags: ee2, snippets

I have a snippet used for navigation that causes a "blank" bit of text to be inserted into the rendered DOM when the encoding for the snippet file is set to utf-8 but not when the snippet encoding is set to ANSI.

The template the snippet is in is set to utf-8 and it renders like this in ALL browsers but you can only see the "blank" when using the webdeveloper tools in Chrome (see screenshot)

[image: blank line before snippet].

Never seen this before but it is my first site using EE 2.9.2. Have not tested in other versions yet.

Anyone have any ideas?

Details: EE 2.9.2, Bootstrap 3.2.0, SnippetSync 1.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snippet file needs to be set for **UTF-8 without BOM**.

Tested on other verions of EE and got consistent results until the snippet was encoded as UTF-8 without BOM.